# Ardent validation and mutators

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, ardent

Here's how my model works. I have a Post model that has a expires_at column. Users provide an integer for the number of days they would like the Post to last.

This was pretty straightforward when I was doing validation in the controller. Just validate the "days" field and then transform that into a future expiration date. But now I'm doing the validation in the model with Ardent and I'm not sure how to accomplish this. I think I need to use a mutator but setting expires_at as an integer seems counterintuitive. I'm also not sure if Ardent validates before or after mutation.

Comment: Give me a link to the package

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out how to do it using the code that removes redundant from data like confirmation fields.

```
public $autoPurgeRedundantAttributes = true;

function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();

    $this->purgeFilters[] = function($key) {
        $purge = array('tempData', 'myAttribute');
        return ! in_array($key, $purge);
    };
}
```

You need to enable `$autoPurgeRedundantAttributes` or the filters won't be called. Then you add a closure to the `$purgeFilters` array which returns false if the provided attribute should be removed. ("days" in this case)

Then you just need to make sure to manually set the field you want validated

```
$this->attributes['days'] = $value;
```

**Edit**: This is in the [official docs](https://github.com/laravelbook/ardent#purge) now. I replaced my code above with theirs.